# comparing file size and modified date

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to build a batch script to confirm both file size and modified date. as of i have been using different commands (diff, comp, and others) that are not giving me the needed outcome. both files are found remotely and are in different time zones so using a dir command output didnt work for me.

ask for computer name or keywork to pull list from a txt file

```
set /P "ComputerName=Please enter the computer name or the word batch to pull from computernames.txt: "
```

compare two locations

```
file1= (fixed server location)\file.zip(or txt)
file2= \\%ComputerName%\m$\file.zip(or txt)
```

compare date modified (this file is modified once a week but can not use time stamp since the file goes out to computers in different time zones and if the copy has an issue it reverts back to last successful file date or "beginning of time" time stamp)

compare size (files that fail a copy with default to a 0 size or size where it got stuck)

```
if file1 = file2 
end or proceed to next file in batch
if file1 does not equal file 2 (both conditions)
export %ComputerName% name to file 
once confirmed end or continue next in txt list
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this will work in your environment, but... while FAT partitions use the local time to save file timestamps, NTFS use UTC time. And this timestamp can be retrieved using `robocopy`

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getFileData "%cd%\file1.zip" file1
    call :getFileData "%cd%\file2.zip" file2

    echo file1 : %file1%
    echo file2 : %file2%

    if "%file1%"=="%file2%" ( 
        echo Both files has the same size/timestamp
    ) else (
        echo Files has different size/timestamp
    )

    goto :eof


:getFileData file returnVar
    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "fileData="

    rem Retrieve file size and time stamp 
    for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%~dp1\." "%~dp1\." "%~nx1" /l /is /ts /nc /ndl /njh /njs 2^>nul
    ') do set "fileData=%%a %%b %%c"

    rem Handle non existing files
    if not defined fileData set "fileData=FileNotFound %random%%random%%random%"

    rem Return or show data
    endlocal & if "%~2"=="" (echo(%fileData%) else (set "%~2=%fileData%")
    exit /b
```

Comment: i changed it a bit but still not getting the needed result.

Comment: @Testdummy, and, where is the difference? what are the values retrieved by the code? how do they differ from the expected behaviour? ....

Comment: i have added the new code below, but the test i ran didnt output an error or any sorts even though i made sure they both contain two different files

Comment: @Testdummy, didn't you get the values from the `echo %file1%` and `echo %file2%`?

Comment: yes, the lines now read call :getFileData "z:\Payload_Work_Area\M_Drive_Cert_Payload.zip" file1 call :getFileData "\\%ComputerName%\m$\M_Drive_Cert_Payload.zip" file2

Comment: @Testdummy, just after the two lines you include, there are two `echo` lines to show information in console. Do you see the output?

Comment: the file just dies once it completes, i even tried the code exactly as you posted and two zip files inside the cd just for good mesaure but it just dies with no text on the screen

Comment: @Testdummy, I've tested it and for me it works. Please, remove the `@echo off` to see where the code fails in your case.

Comment: it looks like it is not picking up the second file in order to make a comparison